# Markov Switching GARCH conditional distribution

Tags: time-series, garch, hidden-markov-model

Given a Markov switching GARCH model

$\epsilon_n=Z_n \sqrt{\sigma_{\Delta_n,n}}$

where $\epsilon_n$ is a time-series of residuals, $Z_n $ is a sequence independent and identically distributed random variables with mean zero and unit variance, and $\left\{ \Delta_n,n\in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$ is a Markov chain.

If we assume that $Z_n$ follow a t-distribution does this mean that each regime will have the degrees of freedom $v$ and only changing the conditional variance  $\sigma_{\Delta_n,n}$ or is the degrees of freedom changing with the regime as well.

Comment: From the equation you wrote down it does not look that the distribution of $Z_n$ would vary with time. Doesn't that answer the question? Oh, I guess you are asking about the distribution of $\epsilon_n$.

Comment: Yes the distribution of Z_n does not change i.e. it is always t for each regime with mean 0 variance 1. On the other hand, the distribution of $\epsilon_n$  is t with mean zero and variance equivalent to the conditional distribution depending on the regime. What I am asking is regarding to the shape parameter.

Comment: The degrees of freedom parameter? Or what shape parameter?

Comment: Yes degrees of freedom sorry for the confusion